# Chevy Malibu 05 cranks but does not start

Tags: malibu, cranks-wont-run

I have a Chevy Malibu '05 4 cly 2.2l  that cranks but does not start.  I already put starting fluid in the intake and it started up and died real quick, which tells me there is spark but no fuel. Does anyone know what's going on?

I also changed out the run/crank relay and it started and stalled again. I will be checking fuel pressure tomorrow.

Comment: Do you have a way to check the fuel pressure?

Comment: No! But I'm going to try tomorrow.  I also changed out the Run/Crank relay or fuel pump relay  I believe is the same thing,  well when I changed it  it started and stalled again.  I don't what it is.  But I am going to check fuel pressure

Comment: Let's not miss the obvious... are you sure there is fuel in the tank?

Answer (score 1):

First thing I would do is check the fuel pressure it should be between 50 - 60 psi. Unless you have a scan tool to command the fuel pump on then this should be done while cranking the engine. The computer commands the fuel pump on for 2 seconds when you turn on the key, and turns it off unless it sees a ignition reference pulses.

Another thing you can do is take off the fuel cap and put you ear near the opening have someone turn on the ignition while you are listening and you should hear the fuel pump come on for the 2 seconds, make sure the key is off for at least 30 seconds before turning it on. If you don't hear it come on at all then you need to make sure it's getting power and ground. Comment on this answer after you have tried that and I can give you more info.

Comment: Another thing to check is to ensure the fuses and relays for the injectors are in good order. This is definitely a fuel issue, so the OP is on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

my sisters malibu maxx had multiple fuel pump problems, turns out the wiring at the tank had an intermittent short

Answer (score -1):

It was the fuel pump  .

I believe it was detective already..
..cause had just changed it out 2 months ago
..

So make sure you get warranty on your parts you purchase..
.

Comment: This appears to be the same user as the OP. If you are the OP please click the contact us link at the bottom of the page and request your two accounts be merged.